# C++ did not generate warning

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-warning

I had a simple typo in my code. I wanted to do `const std::string a = b + "bar";` but instead accidentally had `const std::string a = a + "bar";` To my surprise, this did not generate any warnings from GCC 9.3.0 even though I compiled with `-std=c++17 -Wall`. Moreover, I did not get a warning for an unused variable `b`. How can that be? What flags should I have passed to GCC to generate at least some warning to catch this problem?

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

namespace {
  const std::string b = "foo";
  const std::string a = a + "bar";
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "a is " << std::quoted(a) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compilers aren't required to emit every possible warning, and you might have stumbled on a case gcc doesn't detect.  Clang detects the invalid use of `a` with `-Wuninitialized`.  If you think gcc should detect this, file a bug.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are using the variable `a`, it has an **indeterminate value** that is either a *trap representation* or a *unspecified value*. It can in some cases(implementation) cause **undefined behavior**.

GCC 11.1.0 does generate warning  it seems as seen [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ESMfFVgTw0G2bbYh)

```
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>



int main()
{
  int a = a + 1;//this generates warning in gcc 11.1.0
    std::string p = p + "some string";//this also generate warning in gcc 11.1.0
  return 0;
}
```

But GCC 9.3.0 only gives warning for `int` as seen [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NIGAuH7S6ZBE2HF8)

On the other hand clang [gives](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NkeyuJkW9R8Wsmqn) warning for both.

Comment: I agree that this is an undefined behavior. This is clearly a bug in my code. The question is how can I get GCC to tell me that at compile time?

Comment: @PaulGrinberg I don't think you can; clang spots it but I can't get GCC to report it - live - https://godbolt.org/z/hqofx3fW1